# Profile management tool cannot create the profile the error in WAS profile creation time

Tags: websphere, filenet-p8, was, filenet-content-engine

1. I installed Installation manager without any errors.
2. I am using WAS 9.0.0.9FP with Java SDK 8.0.3.0.
3. The last step in profile creation completed page(In the last page) in WebSphere Customization Toolbox I am facing the bellow the error. I gather the error log file in "AppSrv01_create".
4. PATH : C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\logs\manageprofiles.
5. I am using SQL server. I checked the java paths. And I tried with "setupCmdLine.bat."
6. When I ran the "launchWsadminListener.bat" file I am getting the below error.

**launchWsadminListener.bat Error:**
"

```
E:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin>launchWsadminListener.bat
Invalid Arguments. The expected arguments are: IPCfilename long name
Could not initialize WsProfileAdminListener
The WsProfileAdminListener class is exciting, due to an Exception.
An Exception was encountered in the WsProfileAdminListener classnull
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ibm.ws.profile.wsadmin.WsProfileAdminListener.isRequestAvailable(WsProfileAdminListener.java:362)
        at com.ibm.ws.profile.wsadmin.WsProfileAdminListener.serviceRequests(WsProfileAdminListener.java:163)
        at com.ibm.ws.profile.wsadmin.WsProfileAdminListener.main(WsProfileAdminListener.java:66)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:101)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:82)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:415)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:176)
```

"

**WebSphere Customization Toolbox Error Code:**

```
com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.actionengine.ant.utils.ANTLogToCmtLogAdapter</logger>
  <level>WARNING</level>
  <class>com.ibm.ws.install.configmanager.logging.LogUtils</class>
  <method>logException</method>
  <thread>37</thread>
  <message>**The exception message is: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program** "C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin\launchWsadminListener.bat" (in directory "E:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profileTemplates\default\actions"): **CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified**</message>
</record>
<record>
```

Answer (score 1):

The script launchWsadminListener.bat requires multiple parameters to run properly which results in the NPE when it was launched manually.

Regarding the root problem of the "CreateProcess error=2" error. Is the Windows machine that is being used a Windows 2016 DataCenter machine?

Please see:
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/472732/websphere-v9-profile-creation-fails-on-windows-ser/